# external hard drive current pending sector (or number of unstable sectors) was 445, but after 0-fill format went back to 0

Tags: external-hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

so is the drive in good condition? the drive is very new and i can exchange it for a new one, if the number is back to 0 and reallocated is also 0, does that mean the hard drive is in perfect health? or does the fact that it was 445 earlier imply that there is a problem with this drive?

all other smart values seem to be normal, other than what is noted below in the comments.

Comment: what program are you using to get the number of unusable/unstable sectors?

Comment: hd tune pro, but ive confirmed it with other programs that read SMART attributes as well.

Comment: also raw read error rate went from 0 to 1 to 4 in about 24 hours, is that a bad sign?

Comment: and another thing, current pending sector current value is 200 but worst is 199, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know very much about what could technically go wrong with a harddrive (other than obvious things like shattered platters, failing motors or crashed heads), but going out on a limb i would guess that whatever program you used to 0-fill the harddrive probably wiped out whatever markers the controller in the drive had written to the sectors in order to mark bad ones as unusable etc.

if you are not adverse to paying for it i would recommend you run [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) on your drive to get a better picture of its status than just what SMART reports.

Comment: SpinRite is overkill ($80 cost versus the price of a new disk) if he's going to swap out the drive anyway. I'd just go to a Windows 7 machine and type `format X: /fs:ntfs /p:1` and write it with zeroes, then send it back.